# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK')

Tags: node.js, quasar, exceljs

readFile gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK')`

ExcelJS: ^4.3.0 
Node JS: v14.18.2

Steps To Reproduce

```js
const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

const fullPath = path.resolve("excelName.xlsx");
await wb.xlsx.readFile(fullPath );


const buffer = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer();
```

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1168) bug filed on the official repo.

Comment: I already read it, but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

For me works this:

```
    upload(fileToUpload: File) {
      this.readFile(fileToUpload, (data) =>this.readDataFromFile(data));
    }

    private readFile(fileToUpload: File, callback) {
       const reader = new FileReader();
       let data;
       reader.onload = function () {
          data = reader.result;
          callback(data);
       }
       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileToUpload);
    }

    private readDataFromFile(data: any) {
       var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
       workbook.xlsx.load(data)
         .then(workbook => {
            console.log(workbook, 'workbook instance');

             workbook.eachSheet((sheet, id) => {
                sheet.eachRow((row, rowIndex) => {
                console.log(row.values, rowIndex);
                });
             });
        });
    }
```

Read excel file as array buffer and with exceljs **not use method readFile**, but **use load**.