# Import a complex xlsx file, manipulate and export the file

Tags: reactjs, exceljs

For my React app, I'm looking for a solution to import an existing xlsx file, modify some cell values and download as an xlsx file. What I have tried:

1. npm xlsx: This library seems to work but it removed all the stylings in the original file which I don't want.

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

const response = await fetch("./PAT_report.xlsx");
const workbookArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const workbook = XLSX.read(workbookArrayBuffer, {
    type: "array",

// Get the first sheet
const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[1];
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

// Modify cell value
const cellF12 = worksheet["F12"];
cellF12.v = 100;

// Export the modified workbook
const modifiedWorkbookArrayBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, {
    type: "array",
    bookType: "xlsx",
    });
const modifiedBlob = new Blob([modifiedWorkbookArrayBuffer], {
   type: "application/octet-stream",
    });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(modifiedBlob);
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = url;
a.download = "modified_export.xlsx";
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

2. npm exceljs: I'm trying to read PAT_report.xlsx file in the same directory but I keep getting error `utils.js:156 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK')`

```
import ExcelJS from "exceljs";

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = await workbook.xlsx.readFile("./PAT_report.xlsx");
```

Is there anything else I could try? Other libraries I found require license purchase.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016333/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-f-ok.  There is also this crusty old fork of xlsx lib that tries to preserve styles: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style.  Honestly it would be best if you could try to look under the hood of some of these libs to see what they are doing but if that is too time consuming beyond your powers then hopefully these links will help. xlsx is a flavour of xml and the libs are just reading and providing a simpler api to deal with it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @stoic_monk It only works in case of uploading new file. I have an existing file in my project and I can't find a way to read it.